# MYSQL Using alias as column in case when

Tags: mysql

How do I select alias as a 'date1' column value?I want to select the alias that will show month & year format like 'Jan-18'. MySQL ver 5.0.
I tried this but didnt work:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) = 1  THEN quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS date1
```

My query :

```
 SELECT 
           SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) = 1  THEN quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS jan 

          ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) = 2 THEN quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS feb

          ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) = 3 THEN quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS mar

          ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) = 4 THEN quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS apr

          ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) = 5 THEN quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS may

          ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) = 6 THEN quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS jun

          ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) = 7 THEN quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS jul

          ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) = 8 THEN quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS aug

          ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) = 9 THEN quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS sep

          ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) = 10 THEN quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS octo

          ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) = 11 THEN quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS nov

          ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) = 12 THEN quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS dece

    FROM
    data2


      WHERE
        date1 >= DATE_SUB('2018-09-11', INTERVAL 11 MONTH) AND  date1 <= DATE_FORMAT('2018-09-11', '%Y-%m-31')

    GROUP BY unit
```

Comment: It looks like you want to do a subquery, but you have quite a lengthy inner query, which holds every record in the tables read locked, so your DB might kick you out.  You might be able to get away with this doing two different queries in a stored procedure, else do two separate queries in your business logic.

Comment: `I tried this but didnt work` ... _What_ didn't work?  You forgot to include this in your question.  Your query certainly looks like it should be doing _something_.  Include sample input and output data for best results.

Comment: You could either hard code it eg 'Jan-18'  (including the quotes) or build the code for submission via a prepared statement. BTW this query may fail if only_full_group_by is set (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: @P.Salmon I don't why the query should fail due to only full group by.  Why would you think that?

Comment: Hi,thanks for response, I just want to alias 'jan','feb' etc as a 'date1' column value so that whenever I pass date parameter it will display format like  'Jan-18','Feb-18' & etc. If possible I tried to avoid hardcode because some of the data involve previous year records.

Comment: The short answer is: no, unless you dynamically generate your SQL statement, you cannot use a column's value as the alias value in your query.

Answer (score 0):

#### It works as follows

```
sum(case when expression = true then 100 else 0 end) -- this will work fine

sum(case when expression = true then 100 else null end) -- this will also work - 
                                                       but gives you nulls even 
                                                       if there is one row
                                                       where the expression is 
                                                       false
```